# TypeORM: How to order by a relation field

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a `Singer` entity and a related `Song` entity

**`Singer` entity**

```
export class Singer {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany( type => Song, Song => Song.user )
    songs: Song[];

}
```

**`Song` entity**

```
export class Song {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToOne( type => Singer, Singer => Singer.songs )
    singer: Singer;

}
```

I want to get all `Songs` ordered by `Singer` name

I searched the docs and GitHub issues but can't find an answer
How can I solve this? better without `QueryBuilder`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As of TypeORM version 0.3.0 you can do the following:

```js
repository.find({
    order: {
        singer: {
            name: "ASC"
        }
    }
})
```

## Before version 0.3.0 (original response)

I don't think it is currently supported by typeorm without the query builder, there is currently a [feature request](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2620) open

With the QueryBuilder it is quite simple though:

```
connection.createQueryBuilder(Song, 'songs')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('songs.singer', 'singer')
   .orderBy('singer.name', 'ASC')
   .getMany();
```

Comment: For the people that only check the accepted answer, `order` now [supports nesting](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/8616#:~:text=Now%20supports%20nested%20order%20by%2Ds%3A).

Comment: I tried this but i got error field does not exist, after some search i found that i have to add my relation to relations property something like this ```repository.find({   relations:{ singer:true } order: { singer: { name: "ASC"  } }})```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue i tried to order by custom column but without query builder because i was using Repository, this is my solution :

```
let res = await this.trackingRepository.findAndCount({
      where: [{ username : Like(`%${searchValue}%`) },
              { action : Like(`%${searchValue}%`) },
              { ip : Like(`%${searchValue}%`) }],
      order: {
        [sortField]: sortOrder === "descend" ? 'DESC' : 'ASC',
      },
      skip: (current - 1) * pageSize,
      take: pageSize,
    });
```

Comment: why this has 2 upvotes, this is not related to the question, we have a problem with ordering by relation entity property.

Comment: @DedaDev this remark will not improve the solution, thank you

Comment: @SalahED thanks for sharing the solution while using repository, I was after this and found your answer useful

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  This worked!

Comment: This solution is vulnerable to CWE-89 (SQL injection) and should not be used as an example.

Comment: I updated my solution to not be vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 9):

This is supported as of [TypeORM 0.3.0](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#030-2022-03-17):

```
songRepository.find({
    order: {
        singer: {
            name: "ASC"
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Try the default order on the entity model

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/sample/sample30-default-order-by/entity/Post.ts

```
@Entity("sample30_post", {
    orderBy: {
        title: "ASC",
        id: "DESC"
    }
})
export class Post {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use the query builder **if you are willing to do the ordering in-memory**. (**Careful:** This implies fetching all data sets first and then conduct the filtering on your node server).

For this, you can delegate the task to a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/). This way, you could still use the `EntityManager` or a `Repository` to query the data.

```
// first fetch the song and include (=join) the
// singer by the foreign key "singer"
var queryResult = await this.entityManager.find(Song, {
  relations: ['singer'],
});

// then use a library like lodash to do the ordering
const songsSortedBySinger = _.orderBy(queryResult, song => song.singer.name);
```

For further reading:

- The `relations` find option is [documented here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#basic-options).
- lodash's orderBy is [documented here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy).

Comment: If I could accept 2 answers, I would've accepted yours as well.
this is the approach I was using, but you explained it in a very nice and elegant way, thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Budget, no worries :) By the way, other ORMs in other languages actually support your requirement. For example in C# the "Entity Framework" allows you to simply write `songs.OrderBy(song => song.singer.name);` and it will automatically perform the join and the sort for you – but unfortunately TypeORM doesn't support this :(

Comment: Do you know if this type of functionality is supported in EF Core?

Comment: Yes defintitely, actually I was talking about "EF Core".

Comment: I see 2 cons here: First you're adding another dependency, and second you're sorting once the data is retrieved, so your not actualy sorting the DB data, but the DB results

Comment: Hi @SebastienH. your points are both valid but I think I've made this already explicitly clear in my first sentence: " *if you are willing to do the **ordering in-memory** by delegating the task to a **library like lodash** [...].*

Answer (score -2):

I think typeorm added support for this feature. In my codebase I use a syntax like this, and it orders the results based on the `singer.name`.

```js
const queryResult = await this.songRepository.find(Song, {
  relations: ['singer'],
  order: {
        'singer.name': 'ASC',
      },
});
```

Answer (score -5):

when you use a Repository:

```
var queryResult = await this.youRepository.find(Song, {
  relations: ['singer'],
  order: {
        name: 'ASC',
      },
});
```