# how to use "where" on a query with entity repository from table relations

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am trying to do a query that with query builder works fine but when I try to do it with entity repository fails.

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Query Builder query**

```
const dispatchHeader2 = await this.dispatchHeaderRepository.createQueryBuilder('dh')
                .innerJoinAndSelect('dh.driver', 'driver')
                .innerJoinAndSelect('dh.vehicle', 'vehicle')
                .innerJoinAndSelect('vehicle.transportCompany', 'vtc')
                .innerJoinAndSelect('dh.order', 'o')
                .where('dh.order_id IN(:...ordersId)', { ordersId })
                .andWhere('o.local_origin = :selected_dc', { selected_dc })
                .getMany()
```

**Query with Entity Repository**

```
const dispatchHeader = await this.dispatchHeaderRepository.find({
                relations: ['driver', 'vehicle', 'vehicle.transportCompany', 'order'],
                where: {
                    order_id: In(ordersId),
                    order: {local_origin:selected_dc }
                }
            })
```

**Relation on BD**

[image]

If i do the query without the

```
order: {local_origin:selected_dc }
```

works fine, if i Add that line all fails

Thanks for the help.

**img from typeorm Docs**

[image]

---

Answering Youba

Dont let me do that
[image]

And the query doesnt give me an error, just an empty result. But the query itself dont take any parameters
[image]

---

Comment: Try to do `{order.local_origin:selected_dc }`

Comment: can you show us the error as well

Comment: @Youba updated! :)

Comment: that syntax is wrong. Maybe `order: { [order.local_origin]: selected_dc  }` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thanks for the comment but Unfortunately dont work :(. Anyways...why you think the syntax is wrong? In the official documentation say its good :o
[https://typeorm.io/#/find-options](Typeorm Docs)

Comment: I meant that `order: { oder.local_origin: selected_dc }` is not a valid js code (in that context)

Comment: You need to use a query builder (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871918/typeorm-how-to-order-by-a-relation-field). Or, you can just sort it when you receive it. Up to you.

Comment: @DemiPixel I am using queryBuilder actually(Code above under "Query Builder query") and you can imagine that works good. I just was trying to use entity manager for do the same thing. The Docs says i CAN do it but it seems i cant lmao.
Well, thank u anyway

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you can see by the type definition of `order` is `[P in EntityFieldsNames<Entity>]?: "ASC" | "DESC" | 1 | -1;` which means only properties in the `Entity` can have `ASC` and `DESC` and that's it.

Comment: nonon, the order is a table name, NOT the property for sorting the results. Unless the name make some kind of inner conflict on the query